# Build PHP with dpkg-buildpackage

Tags: php, ubuntu, compilation, dpkg

Trying to build PHP with command:

```
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -d
```

But got an error:

```
Thank you for using PHP.

config.status: creating php5.spec
config.status: creating main/build-defs.h
config.status: creating scripts/phpize
config.status: creating scripts/man1/phpize.1
config.status: creating scripts/php-config
config.status: WARNING:  '../scripts/php-config.in' seems to ignore the --datarootdir setting
config.status: creating scripts/man1/php-config.1
config.status: creating sapi/cli/php.1
config.status: creating main/php_config.h
config.status: executing libtool commands
config.status: executing default commands
/bin/sh: 10: --with-zlib-dir=/usr: not found
make: *** [configure-apache2-stamp] Error 127
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build gave error exit status 2
```

What's wrong? Zlib installed.

OS: Server Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: It tells you what's wrong...

Comment: `10` is not a command.